# Java "handshake_failure exception" at runtime after installing, but not when running from intelliJ

Tags: java, networking, https, client

I made a java application that connects to my website and makes a GET request to it.:

https://bodytracker.net

Currently, if I build and run my Java application within intelliJ it runs perfectly, successfully connects, and properly receives and prints the GET request.

But if I use the [jpackage tool](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html) to install my application, running it as an installed application causes a handshake_failure. I cannot figure out what the difference between running my application in intelliJ vs as an installed application would be that could cause this.

Line 3 triggers a handshake_failed error. I dont set up any sort of network configurations/rules before these lines.

```
1  HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
2  HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create("http://www.bodytracker.net/version"))
                        .GET()
                        .build();
3  HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request,HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
4  double updateVersion = Double.parseDouble(response.body());
```

Comment: Hey @wyit . What happened to bodytracker.net? I saw you asking on Cronometer's forums about an API. Since there still isn't any, I'm thinking of trying to implement an unofficial one. If you'd like to help collaborate on that, message me on Telegram: https://t.me/c4s3yj0n3s

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I am leaving this question up because I see no other questions that involve the same circumstances.

Run java in 'debug mode' and intelliJ adds the following argument:
"-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:51967,suspend=y,server=n"

Adding this argument to my jpackage install succesfully solved the issue and my client now connects to my website without issue.